# Submiting spark application (fat-jar)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm reading spark documentation and now I'm on the section [submitting-application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html). They said:

> If your code depends on other projects, you will need to package them
>   alongside your application in order to distribute the code to a Spark
>   cluster. To do this, ***create an assembly jar (or “uber” jar) containing***
>   ***your code and its dependencies***.

Is it necessary? Why can't we, say, use assembly plugin and put dependencies into `lib/` directory and then add it to driver classpath?

Comment: That would only be easy if you're working with a distributed FS. Otherwise, you'll have to make the JAR available on all nodes. isn't it ?

Comment: @philantrovert Don't quite understand what you mean. In client deploy mode we run out driver program only on a single machine...

Comment: The driver doesn't run executor code, only the application master. The executors need to able to have a classpath of all libraries available